# How to animate circles when the loop of drawing them ends p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, animation, editor, p5.js

I'm trying to make lots of random spots appear on the screen and then animate them by doing spot.x++; . Why doesn't [my code](https://editor.p5js.org/mirorredturtle@gmail.com/sketches/Bkp94lPu7) animate them once the loop is over, and how can I make the code animate once the loop is over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, good advice from Wes Lord. You're creating the spots but not storing them. If you create an array for your spots you can then start to animate them.

This is a really simple amendment to your code but should do what you were trying to do.

```
var spots = []; // array of spots

var col = {
  r: 200,
  g: 5,
  b: 100,
  a: 180
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

// Create spots
  for (var i=0; i<50; i++) {
    spots.push(new Spot());
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  noStroke();
  for (var i=0; i<spots.length; i++) {
    spots[i].move();
    spots[i].display();
  }
}

// Spot class
function Spot() {
  this.x = random(width);
  this.y = random(height);
  this.g = random(5, 255);
  this.a = random(150, 180);
  this.diameter = 20;

  this.move = function() {
    this.x += 1;
  };

  this.display = function() {
    fill(col.r, col.g, col.b, col.a);   
    col.r = this.x / 1.5 + 100;
    col.g = this.g;
    col.b = this.y;
    col.a = this.a;
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.diameter, this.diameter);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a spot object for *each* circle you want to draw. Arrays are great for storing stuff like this.
Then, every draw loop you have to increment *each of those spots*, and re-draw each circle.

---

**Let's step through your code:**
(To simplify, I'm going to pretend you're drawing 2 circles instead of 36.)

`spot` starts as a single data object with x = 50 and y = 50.

You draw one circle at `spot`'s coordinates (50, 50). That circle stays there.
Then you randomize the values in `spot`, so now it might be x = 231.3, y = 4.2, and draw a new circle at those coordinates. That circle has been drawn there and will stay there.

Now you take `spot`, which is still just a single data object with random coordinates in it, and you increment x. `spot.x` becomes 232.3, 233.3, 234.3... but you never call code to re-draw the circles.

Even if you *did* draw a circle again at `spot`'s new coordinates, it wouldn't affect your original circle at 50, 50.

(If you add the line `console.log(spot);` to your `draw()` function, you'll see what I mean.)